# How can I add a form as an item of a menu in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, openid-connect

I'm working with the [OpenID Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect) module to connect a Drupal 7 site with an OpenID provider as a client. So far, I managed to get the module up and running, registering and logging users with my provider, just by using the out-of-the-box functionalities and the provided login block.

What I'm trying to achieve now is to place the form that the block provided by the module renders as a link in my main menu.

I've been able to add a link in my menu by altering the module's `hook_menu` like so:

```
$items[''] = array(
    'title' => 'OpenID Connect',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('openid_connect_login_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

But that doesn't work as intended.

What I'd like would be to either insert the form that the module renders in the block into the menu item or generate a link that works as the form created in the block does.

Alternatively, I could render the block with the form hidden, and create a menu link that doesn't redirect to a page but just finds and submits the form via JS, but I also don't know how to go about doing that.

I'm relatively new to Drupal and getting dizzy with all the reading, so I come to you fellow internet friends for help; any and all advice and direction is welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to Just Remove quote replace  `$items[''] ` by `$items[] ` if you implement `hook_menu` don't forget to add ` return $items;` and `clear cache` it's important ?

Answer (score 0):

hook_menu allow to define menu items and page callbacks.
you have to add the page path inside your $items like this : $items['path']. 
Then clear cache to make change be effect and access to your due this path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement hook_menu in your module. Example:

```
<?php
function mymodule_menu() {

  $items['mymodule/links'] = array(
    'title' => 'OpenID Connect', 
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
    'access arguments' => array('openid_connect_login_form'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  return $items;
}
?>
```

Please clear cache after any changes in drupal code or setting.